# Insert external pictures in tikz, but cannot find the picture

Tags: latex, pdflatex, tikz

I try to insert an external picture into tikz editor, and the code is:

```
 \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{IC.png}};
```

However, it is reported that the picture cannot be found. I was wondering how to specify the path of this picture. (I try to put the tikz file and the picture in the same directory but it does not work)

Comment: Not sure about tikz editor but it must be something like this:  `\graphicspath{{C:/Latex/Figures/}}` if your file `IC.png` is present in, say, `C:/Latex/Figures/`

Comment: The code `\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} \begin{document} \begin{tikzpicture} \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{IC.png}}; \end{tikzpicture} \end{document}` should compile sweetly if the file IC.png is in the same folder as your tex file. You should post your minimal code for us to say further :)